# 特定のファイルを開く際に、いつもと encoding を替えるには？

Tags: emacs

特定のファイルがあって、そのファイルを開くときにはいつもとは違う encoding で開きたいとします。
これを実現するには、どうしたらいいでしょうか。

具体的には、 vagrant 上の emacs で /vagrant/scratch.txt を開くときに、 windows 共用のファイルとしていつもこれを利用しているので、 `cp932-dos` で開いてほしい、と思っています。
このファイルは、scratch 用の、中身はいわゆるなんでも書くメモ帳なので、たまに中身を空っぽにして保存したりなどしていて、そのたびに encoding を指定しなおす、をやっているのでこれをどうにかしたいと考えています。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`file-coding-system-alist`に、ファイル名の正規表現とencodingとのマッピングが定義されています。変更するには`modify-coding-system-alist`を使います

```
(modify-coding-system-alist 'file "^/vagrant/scratch.txt$" 'cp932-dos)
```

第2引数は正規表現なので、上では完全一致するようなパターンにしていますが、他にもencodingを変えたいファイルがあればパターンをいじってください。

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Recognize-Coding.html

Answer (score 2):

`find-file-hook` を使う方法があります。

```lisp
(add-hook 'find-file-hook
          (lambda ()
            (and (string= (buffer-file-name) (expand-file-name "/vagrant/scratch.txt"))
                 (setq buffer-file-coding-system 'cp932-dos))))
```

`(expand-file-name "/vagrant/scratch.txt")` の `expand-file-name` は無くても結果は同じですが、対象のファイルパスに `~` を使う場合を考慮して入れてあります。

Answer (score 1):

下記をscratch.txtに書いておくというのは如何でしょうか。

```
Local variables:
  buffer-file-coding-system: cp932-dos
End:
```

Answer (score 0):

C-x RET c cp932-dos C-x C-f すれば cp932-dos で開けます。

C-x RET c は universal-coding-system-argument と言うのだそうで、
後続の I/O コマンドの文字コードを指定するコマンドだそうで。

ただし、いちど読み込んじゃっだファイルに対して文字コード指定して読み直すには
C-x C-f では読み直しをやってくれません。代わりに M-x revert-buffer を使います。